# Cannot determine the main class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am working in IntelliJ IDEA and I ran this code.(image attached) and got the error
 "Exception in thread "main" acm.util.ErrorException: Cannot determine the main class."

It works in Eclipse but not IntelliJ IDEA. Thing is I'd like to use IntelliJ and any help will be very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please post some code.  It's the problem, not IntelliJ.  Looked at the image.  The answer is obvious: there IS no main method.

Comment: thing is same code runs in Eclipse just fine. I am actually following a Stanford course online and the instructor runs it without any main method.

Comment: You won't get through a Stanford course unless you can deduce that you should have a main method.  Add one.

Comment: You should prefer IntelliJ - it's the best IDE on the market.  Please add this code to a main.  That's the proper way to do it.  That's correct Java.  Eclipse misleads you by allowing you to run without one.  It won't work anywhere else but Eclipse as written.

Comment: I did and it worked. I prefer IntelliJ myself. I guess i am not experienced enough in Java to know that Eclipse might mislead me...

Answer (score 0):

I learned Eclipse might mislead sometimes and the recommended practice is to have a main function. I added one and it worked.

[Added a main function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqFYI.png)

Comment: It's not 'recommended practice'.  This is how the language works.  What Eclipse did was add one for you behind the scenes without telling you.  It's misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Class with main function is the main class so add main to your code.

Comment: I did. Thank you. I hope every beginner like myself will know this because Eclipse totally misleads.

Comment: Eclipse is actually doing a lot of work automatically for users which is not helpful for learning.

Comment: I couldn't agree more.